# Using jQuery and sprites

Tags: jquery, css, sprite

I am looking for a way to animate my sprites with jquery. When I hover over the image, it fades in. then when I hover off. it fades out.

CSS:

```
nav ul { position: relative; z-index: 1000;  margin: -26px 0 0 11px; overflow: hidden; }
nav ul li { display: inline; }
nav ul li a { background: url(../images/nav-sprite.png); display: block; float: left; text-indent: -999px; margin: 0 auto; width: 667px; }
nav ul a#nav-1 { background-position: 0 0;  height: 48px; width: 103px; }
nav ul a#nav-2 { background-position: -103px 0;  height: 48px; width: 129px; }
nav ul a#nav-3 { background-position: -234px 0;  height: 48px; width: 156px; }
nav ul a#nav-4 { background-position: -392px 0;  height: 48px; width: 147px; }
nav ul a#nav-5 { background-position: -541px 0;  height: 48px; width: 124px; }
nav ul a#nav-1:hover { background-position: 0 48px; }
nav ul a#nav-2:hover { background-position: -103px 48px; }
nav ul a#nav-3:hover { background-position: -234px 48px; }
nav ul a#nav-4:hover { background-position: -392px 48px; }
nav ul a#nav-5:hover { background-position: -541px 48px; }
```

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: Sorry. How can i make the hover sprite have a fade effect?

Comment: Not directly related, but here's a fun jQuery sprites implementation ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851896/rotate-sprite-javascript/3852360#3852360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing specific to sprites in this question. You can always use the usual method, combining the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) event with the [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto) function to get the opacity animation you need.

```
$("nav ul a").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(300, 0.4);
}).fadeTo(0, 0.4);
```

If you need to, you can also add a CSS fallback:

```
nav ul a {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

nav ul a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

See it working live here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/CNC6W/

---

Well, it's simple to fix - try adding a background to the `ul` element, then giving it a `border-radius` to make sure the rounded corners stay.

```
nav ul {
    background: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;   /* Not sure about the actual radius 
                             you're using - these are guesses */
}
```

You might also want to increase the starting opacity from 0.4 to something higher, and the duration to something lower than 300.

Comment: Really nice! But the whole nav is now transparent, I only need the hover effect doing it.  heres the site im working on atm. http://elektrikhost.com/

Comment: @Kawohi And so? What difference does that make? And more importantly, have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/43-how-to-use-css-sprites/) screen cast from CSS Tricks. It deals with animating CSS sprites.

Comment: Yes but the animation is nothing to do with the sprites.