# what are <hover-sprite> tags in html and how to use effectively?

Tags: html, css, 3d

I have been admiring the remix 3d site images found here: https://www.remix3d.com/board/3vkCqsxjqeH

when you hover your mouse over the image catalog the photos move.

I want to replicate this and am having trouble doing so. Inspecting the elements reveals that one of the interactive cards uses the  tag, which I have never seen. This is the div for that card:

```
<div role="listitem" aria-setsize="32" aria-posinset="1" aria-label="Grid Item 1: " class="gallery-grid-item visible">
    <creation-item id="ember551" class="ember-view">
        <div data-test-selector="creation-item" draggable="true" class="item-content  ">
            <creation-router id="ember556" class="ember-view" aria-hidden="true">
                <route-to id="ember561" role="none" class="ember-view"><a tabindex="-1" title="Create an ocean scene" href="/details/0ce93dec1a8e43f6b262faff8b34015f" id="ember566" class="ember-view" aria-label="Model Create an ocean scene - Activate to go to Create an ocean scene's page.">
                        <!---->
                        <div class="item-image" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-575="575">
                            <div class="item-image-inner">
                                <hover-sprite id="ember580" class="is-loaded ember-view">
                                    <div style="-webkit-transform: translateY(-6.666666666666667%); -ms-transform: translateY(-6.666666666666667%); transform: translateY(-6.666666666666667%); width: 100%; height: 1500%; background-image: url(https://encoding.assets.remix3d.com:443/003/0ce93dec1a8e43f6b262faff8b34015f/005/08586725131056667658993017976cu01/de7fa282fa004472a8ae94e0460051ea?format=jpg);" class="hover-sprite-sheet"></div>
                                    <!---->
                                </hover-sprite>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </a>
                </route-to>
            </creation-router>
            <div class="item-card-bottom">
                <creation-router id="ember581" class="ember-view">
                    <route-to id="ember582" role="none" class="ember-view"><a title="Create an ocean scene" href="/details/0ce93dec1a8e43f6b262faff8b34015f" id="ember587" class="ember-view" aria-label="Model Create an ocean scene - Activate to go to Create an ocean scene's page.">
                            <div data-test-selector="creation-item-name" class="item-name" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-588="588">
                                <div class="item-name-text">Create an ocean scene</div>
                                <span class="remix-icon icon-chevron-right-med"></span>
                            </div>

                        </a>
                    </route-to>
                </creation-router>
                <a data-test-selector="creation-item-add-button" title="Add to board" tabindex="0" href="#" id="ember593" class="item-add-button remix-icon icon-add ember-view"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </creation-item>

</div>
```

How can i go about replicating this/how are hover sprites used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site looks to be using the [Ember.js](https://emberjs.com/) framework, which allows defining of custom HTML tags ([Components](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/)), ie `<hover-sprite>`.

As for the effect you see when mousing over a catalog item ... for each item they've created an [image sprite](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) ([example sprite](https://encoding.assets.remix3d.com/003/0000000900000000003aed3b00000000/005/08586774635255468956358046288/70666a19c2ed4293971094dc40ba1d8b?format=jpg) from Remix 3D). The sprite is sequential snapshots of an object in rotation. Based on cursor location the sprite is shifted to reveal the next snapshot in the sequence of rotation.

You don't need to use Ember.js to create this effect. Here's an example using jQuery to demonstrate a solution : [Rotate sprite javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851896/rotate-sprite-javascript).

Comment: do you have any idea how to make those image sprites for a 3d model from solidworks?

Comment: @hammertime, sorry I don't have any experience with solidworks. You could just take screenshots of the various angles from the program and merge them together into a sprite using something like photoshop. Hope that helps!