# creating 2d image sprite from 3d solidworks model

Tags: javascript, 3d, sprite, solidworks

Im looking to replicate what is done on the remix 3d site images found here: https://www.remix3d.com/board/3vkCqsxjqeH

for each item they've created an [Image Sprite](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) ([example sprite](https://encoding.assets.remix3d.com/003/0000000900000000003aed3b00000000/005/08586774635255468956358046288/70666a19c2ed4293971094dc40ba1d8b?format=jpg) from Remix 3D). The sprite is sequential snapshots of an object in rotation. Based on cursor location the sprite is shifted to reveal the next snapshot in the sequence of rotation.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to generate these image sprites from a 3d model in solidworks, or if i would have to go in and manually make them with images from different angles on the model.

I can use almost any filetype provided in solidworks to complete this.

[this is another example of what i want with images from my 3d model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851896/rotate-sprite-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to generate a rotation animation using the [Rotation Animation Motion Wizard](http://help.solidworks.com/2019/English/SolidWorks/motionstudies/t_rotating_model_anim_wizard.htm) of Motion Study and then export the result in the format of the [sequence of images in bmp/png/tiff](http://help.solidworks.com/2019/English/SolidWorks/motionstudies/HIDD_SAVEANIMATION.htm).

Alternatively you can automate this task using SOLIDWORKS API.

Comment: you are a hero!